# Apache session works differently on the same server

Tags: php, apache, session, centos, server

The situation is we have a local server machine with Apache on it, and two projects on the same local server.

The problem is when we set up session.gc_maxlifetime = 10, for example, the server logs out on project N1 after 10 seconds with deleting the session file successfully, but on the other project N2, the session files are not deleted and the session is not logged out.

session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor are both set up to 1.

What could be the reason of that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of PHP garbage collector, which **may** or not remove sessions after desired period of time. See explanation:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

> *session.gc_maxlifetime* specifies the number of seconds after which
>   data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage
>   collection **may** occur during session start (depending on
>   session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: @Zarebski, Thank you for your answer. Both probability and divisor parameters are set to 1, which is the same as 100%. So we change may to must. I don't think that is the reason here...

Comment: I think the important thing here is _Garbage collection MAY occur during session start_. If there is no activity on the site i.e. sessions being started then GC will not get activated anyway. It does not run as a seperate activity always looking for garbage, it only happens as part of some other session processing activity